# IronRouter dataNotFound on blog post

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I would like show 404 page if `blog/xyz` don't work. So i've add dataNotFound on my routes.js, but i've no result :

```
Router.route('/blog/:slug', {
  name: 'blogPost',
  parent: 'blog',
  itemName: function () {
    return this.data().post.title;
  },
  data: function () {

    let post = Posts.findOne({
      'slug': this.params.slug
    });

    return {
      post,
      profil
    };

  }
});

Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {
  only: 'blogPost'
});
```

If i test wrong url with `blog/ojhojeofje`, i don't have 404 page, just post without data.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to register `dataNotFound` as plugin instead of in `onBeforeAction`:

```js
Router.plugin('dataNotFound', { only: ['blogPost'] });
```

Secondly the `dataNotFound` plugin works by checking if your route `data()` returns a falsy value. Since you want to load multiple data object in your `data()` function, you need to alter your function so that it will return something falsy if the post is not found. For example you can simply do this:

```js
data: function () {
  let post = Posts.findOne({
    'slug': this.params.slug
  });
  if (!post) {
    return false;
  }
  ...
```

Note that you also need to make sure that your subscription to the `Posts` collection is ready before you run `data` in order to avoid going to the not found page unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you ! Work perfectly !